# When i overload constructor it doesn't work properly C++

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class sum
{
    protected:
        int num, rang;
    public:
        sum(){
            cin >> num;
            cin >> rang;
        }
        sum(int num, int rang){
            int n = 10;
            int sum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < rang; i++){
                num += n; 
                sum += num;
            }
            num = sum;
            cout << num << '\n';
        }
};

int main()
{
    sum obj;    
    return 0;
}
```

When I call second costructor (overload constructor), it should print sum, but it prints nothing, I think it even isn't calling by previous censtructor, why?

Comment: Yes, you don't call the second constructor. Where do you think it should get called.

Comment: you should include input and expected output in the quesiton. its not clear why you expect output in the code you posted because it doesnt call `sum(int,int)` or do you think it does?

Comment: You need to call the overloaded constructor like so `sum obj(4,5);`

Comment: Hint: add some `cout`s and you'll see what happens. Your code works as expected. It calls the `sum()` which does the two `cin`s and then the program quits. The `sum(int num, int  rang)` constructor is never called.

Answer (score 2):

Because in your given code, you never create an object using the second constructor (aka **parameterized constructor**). That constructor will be **implicitly called** by the compiler when you create an object of type `sum` by passing 2 `int` arguments as shown below:

```
sum obj(4, 5);// compiler implicitly calls the parameterized constructor
```